# Can docker port forward to a unix file socket on the host container?

Tags: docker, unix-socket

Running the following command fails:

```
sudo docker run -p unix:///tmp/file.sock:44444 -d image_name
```

Is something wrong with my port forwarding syntax or is a configuration like this not possible?

Comment: You may be able to put the UNIX socket in a volume which the host can access / mount to another container. I'd recommend you simply listen on a port rather than a UNIX socket.

Comment: The idea behind it was to increase speed, because with unix sockets I would be able to avoid the network overhead that is inherent in ports

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Docker's `-p` syntax won't take a unix socket:

```
-p=[]      : Publish a container᾿s port to the host (format:
             ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort |
             hostPort:containerPort)
```

One solution would be to:

- Run your container without any `-p` specification, we'll name it `"cont1"` (`--name cont1`)
- Run a second container which:

  - [Bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) the unix socket (`-v /tmp/file.sock:/tmp/file.sock`) to have it accessible from within the container
  - [Links](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#working-with-links-names) to the first container (`--link cont1:cont1`) to be able to connect to it
  - Runs a tool such as [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to route traffic from the unix socket to the `"cont1:4444"` endpoint

I'm not a socat expert, but the address specification you'll need should look like this: `UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/file.sock,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:cont1:4444`

Comment: What if the unix socket on the host is not mapped on a file, that is an abstract namespace socket, such as (as reported by lsof): ```aesm_serv 26473 aesmd    6u  unix 0xffff88021c494b00      0t0   291424 @sgx_aesm_socket_base type=STREAM```

Comment: Someone was nice enough to build a container that does the above: https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/socat/

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is partially correct however since you can only link directories, which means you need to link the directory of the socket instead of the socket itself.

The following did it for me when I wanted to connect a postgres socket.

`docker run -p 5432:5432 -v /run/postgresql:/run/postgresql -d --name postgres postgres`

What this does is link the postgres socket file to your host system.

Comment: Still not supported for mac? https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/483

Comment: I have use the -v option to link non-directory files (regular files). However because the server creates the socket, you need to bind a directory. (check that the server has permission to write to this directory.