# Docker, how to expose a socket over a port for a Django Application

Tags: python, django, docker

I currently have `supervisor` serving my Django Application which I then `expose` on port `8002` in my Docker file. This all works ok...

```
[program:app]
command=gunicorn app.core.wsgi:application -c /var/projects/app/server/gunicorn.conf
user=webapp

backlog     = 2048
chdir       = "/var/projects/apps"
bind        = "0.0.0.0:8002"
pidfile     = "/var/run/webapp/gunicorn.pid"
daemon      = False
debug       = False
```

In Docker

```
# Expose listen ports
EXPOSE 8002
```

However, I have been told it is better to use a `socket` over a port but, I'm unsure how to "EXPOSE" a socket in my Docker file. This is how far I have got:

New supervisor config....

```
backlog     = 2048
chdir       = "/var/projects/apps"
bind        = "unix:/var/run/webapp/gunicorn.sock"
pidfile     = "/var/run/webapp/gunicorn.pid"
daemon      = False
debug       = False
```

Docker

```
# Expose listen ports
EXPOSE ???? (may be unix:/var/run/webapp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;???)
```

How do I expose the socket?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can docker port forward to a unix file socket on the host container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956322/can-docker-port-forward-to-a-unix-file-socket-on-the-host-container)

Comment: @satoru thats using the RUN command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EXPOSE` only works with UDP and TCP sockets.

If you want to make a Unix domain socket available outside of your container, you will need to mount a host directory inside the container and then place the socket there.  For example, if you were to:

```
docker run -v /srv/webapp:/var/run/webapp ...
```

Then `/var/run/webapp/gunicorn.sock` in your container would be `/srv/webapp/gunicorn.sock` on your host.

Of course, this assumes that you have something running on your host, or in another container that also has access to `/srv/webapp`, that is able to consume that socket and use it to provide a service.